# identify javascript crackme encryption method algorithm

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering

Is there any way to identify encryption method ?

In this crackme example they use rc4

It took me couple of hours iterating over encryption methods in some site with extracting 'input128' value

Update to clarify:
there is a text input element on the screen and you enter a value (which is set into **_inputValue**), afterwards you click on a button, the function executes, in the last lines, if **selectedOption** is 2 it will print "good"
otherwise there are 5 bad options in the optionsArr.

after unpacking and cleaning the main function is :

```
var mainFunction = function(e) {
    var arr256 = new Array();
    for (var index = 0; index < 256; index++) arr256[(index).toString()] = index;
    var varX = 0;
    var _inputValue = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]['value'];
    for (var index = 0; index < 256; index++) {
        var secret = 'click';
        varX = (varX + arr256[(index).toString()] + secret.charCodeAt(index % 5)) % 256;
        arr256[(index).toString()] ^= arr256[(varX).toString()];
        arr256[(varX).toString()] ^= arr256[(index).toString()];
        arr256[(index).toString()] ^= arr256[(varX).toString()];
    }
    index = varX = 0;
    var cmpStr = '';
    for (var index2 = index; index2 < _inputValue.length; index2 += 2) {
        index = (index + 1) % 256;
        varX = (varX + arr256[(index).toString()]) % 256;
        arr256[(index).toString()] ^= arr256[(varX).toString()];
        arr256[(varX).toString()] ^= arr256[(index).toString()];
        arr256[(index).toString()] ^= arr256[(varX).toString()];
        var parsedInt = parseInt(_inputValue.substr(index2, 2), 16);
        var idxAtArr = arr256[(index).toString()];
        var xAtArr = arr256[(varX).toString()];
        var secondVal = arr256[((idxAtArr + xAtArr) % 256).toString()];
        var xorVal = parsedInt ^ secondVal;
        cmpStr += String.fromCharCode(xorVal);
    }
    var selectedOption = cmpStr.charCodeAt(cmpStr.charCodeAt(0) % cmpStr.length) % 6;
    if (cmpStr != 'input128' && selectedOption == 2) selectedOption++;
    optionsArr[(selectedOption).toString()]();
};
```

Comment: You can't ask for tools here. The [help/on-topic] says clearly *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: You *were* asking for tools. You're not now. Thanks for editing. Close vote retracted.

Comment: I removed my close vote. Not running over anybody. You posted an off-topic question, I voted to close it (and was courteous enough to explain why). You edited to make it on topic, I removed my close vote. You're assuming the downvote is mine. Assumptions are not a good idea, and can often be insulting when you make accusations. I explained my close vote. Where did I say I was downvoting?

Comment: my bad, i'm sorry, you deserve an upvote for that

Comment: So is `mainFunction()` your attempt to `reverse-engineer` some encoded value or is that the function you are trying to simplify so you can understand what it is doing? I'm a little unclear to your question....

Comment: @NewToJS yes, also I've found out it is using rc4 encryption by just trying all the available encryption methods on some site

Comment: @zaph the code is properly formatted, feels like you rushed to comment, the forloop to insert number 1..256 to array is not, but its a simple line

Comment: I started answering before it was formatted. There is no excuse for posting randomly formatted code in the first place, there is no excuse for writing such code.

Comment: @zaph you should have seen it in before unpacking.. u would have been furious

Comment: @IddoE Reading back on the comments *"btw it's a question from an interview i had which i think it's too harsh"* if this is for an interview don't you think it would be best you go at this on your own to see if you can do it? It would be the point of having this as part of any "interview" is to find  the right applicant for whatever it is you are applying for?

Comment: @NewToJS to clarify, this question is from an interview two years ago, I'm learning RE so I brought this question to practice and understand if there is anyway to detect encryption method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first & clean solution

```
Password: <input/><br/>
<button>Check</button>
<script id="urchin">
    (function () {
        var optionsArr = [
            function () {
                console.warn("boo")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn(":(")
            },
            function () {
                console.log("Congratz!")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("allmost there")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("muhaha")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("nahhh")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("not even close")
            }
        ];
        var mainFunction = function () {
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                arr[i] = i;
            }
            var inputVal = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
            var varX = 0;
            var secret = 'click';
            for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 256; i2++) {
                varX = (varX + arr[i2] + secret.charCodeAt(i2 % 5)) % 256;
                arr[i2] ^= arr[varX];
                arr[varX] ^= arr[i2];
                arr[i2] ^= arr[varX];
            }
            var idx = varX = 0;
            var cmpStr = '';
            var key = 'input128';
            for (var i3 = idx; i3 < key.length; i3 += 1) {
                idx = (idx + 1) % 256;
                varX = (varX + arr[idx]) % 256;
                arr[idx] ^= arr[varX];
                arr[varX] ^= arr[idx];
                arr[idx] ^= arr[varX];

                var hex2int = key.charCodeAt(i3);
                var charCode = hex2int ^ arr[(arr[idx] + arr[varX]) % 256];

                var hexCharCode = charCode.toString(16);
                if (hexCharCode.length == 1) hexCharCode = '0' + hexCharCode;

                cmpStr += hexCharCode;
            }
            alert('code is ' + cmpStr);
            var selectedOption = cmpStr.charCodeAt(cmpStr.charCodeAt(0) % cmpStr.length) % 6;

            if (cmpStr != key && selectedOption == 2) selectedOption++;
            optionsArr[selectedOption]();
        };
        var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        if (typeof(btn.addEventListener) != typeof(mainFunction)) {
            btn.attachEvent('onclick', mainFunction);
        } else {
            btn.addEventListener('click', mainFunction, true);
        }
        btn = document.getElementById('urchin');
        btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
    })();
</script>
```

or brute forcing because it doesn't only use rc4 it also convert to hex which was painful

```
Password: <input/><br/>
<button>Check</button>
<script id="urchin">
    (function () {
        var optionsArr = [
            function () {
                console.warn("boo")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn(":(")
            },
            function () {
                console.log("Congratz!")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("allmost there")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("muhaha")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("nahhh")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("not even close")
            }
        ];

        function decryptFunc(inputVal, arr) {
            var idx = 0, idx2 = 0;
            var decrypt = '';
            for (var i4 = idx; i4 < inputVal.length; i4 += 2) {
                idx = (idx + 1) % 256;
                idx2 = (idx2 + arr[idx]) % 256;
                arr[idx] ^= arr[idx2];
                arr[idx2] ^= arr[idx];
                arr[idx] ^= arr[idx2];
                var curHex = inputVal.substr(i4, 2);
                var hex2int = parseInt(curHex, 16);
                var charCode = hex2int ^ arr[(arr[idx] + arr[idx2]) % 256];
                decrypt += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
            }
            return decrypt;
        }

        var mainFunction = function () {
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                arr[i] = i;
            }
            var inputVal = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
            var i2 = 0;
            var secret = 'click';
            var originalKey = 'input128';

            for (var i3 = 0; i3 < 256; i3++) {
                i2 = (i2 + arr[i3] + secret.charCodeAt(i3 % 5)) % 256;
                arr[i3] ^= arr[i2];
                arr[i2] ^= arr[i3];
                arr[i3] ^= arr[i2];
            }

            var decrypt = null;
            var codeFound = false;
            var s = '';
            var idx = 1;
            while (!codeFound) {
                for (var h = 0; h < 256; h++) {
                    var hexLetter = h.toString(16);
                    var cmpKey = s + hexLetter;
                    decrypt = decryptFunc(cmpKey, arr);
                    // restore arr
                    arr = [99, 116, 115, 37, 16, 120, 211, 90, 197, 22, 166, 63, 146, 59, 123, 237, 93, 44, 76, 118, 168, 91, 55, 187, 62, 220, 135, 49, 127, 185, 153, 8, 66, 155, 152, 181, 117, 149, 31, 87, 169, 6, 172, 34, 101, 134, 107, 157, 199, 231, 124, 2, 243, 35, 241, 139, 68, 3, 159, 86, 77, 225, 105, 29, 144, 19, 32, 42, 227, 147, 133, 15, 160, 73, 190, 148, 82, 97, 170, 201, 212, 14, 18, 13, 193, 121, 143, 141, 182, 122, 21, 108, 112, 111, 217, 60, 250, 27, 137, 244, 191, 38, 171, 214, 248, 132, 228, 43, 232, 213, 223, 129, 28, 64, 247, 205, 138, 95, 202, 235, 61, 119, 224, 88, 238, 206, 230, 94, 195, 5, 179, 54, 72, 92, 136, 98, 188, 200, 173, 226, 198, 4, 71, 196, 126, 9, 69, 110, 84, 48, 85, 210, 30, 180, 229, 216, 162, 56, 75, 0, 67, 253, 163, 167, 53, 26, 7, 12, 174, 57, 130, 194, 209, 165, 1, 140, 183, 70, 23, 89, 150, 25, 145, 104, 233, 74, 142, 151, 222, 65, 207, 96, 154, 218, 106, 131, 255, 109, 254, 33, 113, 164, 203, 40, 246, 83, 192, 236, 189, 78, 158, 234, 177, 175, 161, 251, 100, 221, 219, 103, 50, 41, 242, 10, 249, 240, 20, 184, 24, 80, 52, 51, 81, 11, 156, 245, 114, 239, 186, 125, 17, 204, 128, 47, 36, 39, 215, 208, 46, 176, 178, 58, 45, 102, 252, 79];
                    if (decrypt == originalKey.substr(0, idx)) {
                        console.log(cmpKey, decrypt);
                        if (hexLetter.length == 1) hexLetter = '0' + hexLetter; // zero padding to convert to hex
                        s += hexLetter;
                        idx++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (decrypt == originalKey) {
                    codeFound = true;
                    console.log('code is', s);
                }
            }

            var selectedOption = decrypt.charCodeAt(decrypt.charCodeAt(0) % decrypt.length) % 6;
            if (decrypt != originalKey && selectedOption == 2) selectedOption++;
            optionsArr[selectedOption]();
        };
        var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        if (typeof(btn.addEventListener) != typeof(mainFunction)) {
            btn.attachEvent('onclick', mainFunction);
        } else {
            btn.addEventListener('click', mainFunction, true);
        }
        btn = document.getElementById('urchin');
        btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
    })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Key-scheduling_algorithm_.28KSA.29) to me. Except this implementation limits the key to just 5 chars for some reason.

Comment: can you explain how did you figure that out ?

Comment: I implemented it before, so I recognized it when I saw it